# ios- adding gelocation in uiimage metadata

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Sir,
    Here i need to add geolocation from metadata to uiimage but after adding i just loading in to photoalbum only but here i need that image,here i have added the source code

```
- (void) saveImage:(UIImage *)imageToSave withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];


        // Get the image metadata (EXIF & TIFF)    
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults objectForKey:latkey];
    float longitude=[defaults floatForKey:longkey];
    float latitude=[defaults floatForKey:latkey];    
    CLLocation * loc=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    NSMutableDictionary *metaDict = nil;
    if ([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] != nil) {
        metaDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]];
        NSDictionary *gpsDict = [self currentLocation:loc];
        if ([gpsDict count] > 0) {
            [metaDict setObject:gpsDict forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
        }
    }
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imageToSave CGImage] metadata:metaDict completionBlock:^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {

        } else {
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"metaDict  :%@",metaDict);


    NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    [library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        NSDictionary *metadata = rep.metadata;
        NSLog(@"%@", metadata);

        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage] ;

        if (iref) {
            capturedImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            // error handling
    }];
}
```

Creates an EXIF field for the current geo location.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary*)currentLocation:(CLLocation *)location{
    NSMutableDictionary *locDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (location != nil) {
        CLLocationDegrees exifLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
        CLLocationDegrees exifLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

        [locDict setObject:location.timestamp forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSTimeStamp];

        if (exifLatitude < 0.0) {
            exifLatitude = exifLatitude*(-1);
            [locDict setObject:@"S" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];
        } else {
            [locDict setObject:@"N" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];
        }
        [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exifLatitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];

        if (exifLongitude < 0.0) {
            exifLongitude=exifLongitude*(-1);
            [locDict setObject:@"W" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];
        } else {
            [locDict setObject:@"E" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];
        }
        [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exifLongitude] forKey:(NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];
    }

    return [locDict autorelease];
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : U can get image add in photo Album like by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570903/iphone-alassetslibrary-get-all-images-and-edit) link.

Now if u have asset then using asset's created date u can know last photo added like this as save date before adding to photo album :

```
NSDate *imgCreateddate = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
if(imgCreateddate isGreaterThan savedDate)
{
  last Photo;
}
```

---

Refer [Adding metadata to iOS images the easy way](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/05/11/adding-metadata-to-ios-images-the-easy-way/) link.

Refer [GusUtils](https://github.com/gpambrozio/GusUtils) for sample code.

Refer [saving-geotag-info-with-photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884060/saving-geotag-info-with-photo-on-ios4-1) link

Comment: here the same way i am adding the geolocation to uiimage but its saved to photoalbum by this line [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imageToSave CGImage] metadata:metaDict completionBlock:^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error)  my question is how can i get the edited uiimage

Comment: same as all other images in photo album using avasset library

Comment: how can i get the lastly added image because by that image i need upload the image