# How we can upload camera roll image automatically to server

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary, camera-roll

How I can upload a camera roll image automatically to server? This same thing implemented in Dropbox and Google Photos and some other apps also. What should I do to achieve such kind of functionality in my app?

Comment: you should take a look here: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/500

Answer (score 0):

dropbox not upload the camera roll images automatically to server or there is no application in iOS which automatically upload images until user give it access permission.

Dropbox not working until user enable  photo access permission.

if you want to upload the images first take all images access using [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/) than send the images to server in background using [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) or [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not a single question, but a paradigm. An entire process, that includes:

- Obtaining authorisation to access the photo library.
- Accessing assets (images/videos) in the user's gallery.
- Uploading to a server.

Read up on all the three, if you want to achieve this. In a nutshell it is as follows:

You use `ALAssetsLibrary` to access assets (the photos and videos in the user's gallery). If the user has not authorized yet, the user will be asked automatically. If the user has authorised access, you can request for assets. If the user has denied access explicitly, you should not attempt to access assets.

See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572508/2082856) answer to see how you can access images using the `ALAssetsLibrary`.

In the success block, you can access the images with :

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage];
```

Once you have the image, you can upload it using any technique (NSURLSession, AFNetworking, etc)

Comment: These are basic things...UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage]; using this you can`t get the edited image :p

Answer (score -1):

are you trying to make it so that when you take a picture with the iOS camera it auto uploads to your server?

I don't believe you can do that, my understanding with dropbox and google on your iOS device is that their app has to be open to upload pictures.  From there it's no big deal to access a user's photos  and allow them to upload one or many pictures.

Dropbox and google also have desktop apps that run on OS X that will auto upload images after the device is plugged into the computer, but I am assuming that isn't what you are asking.

Comment: Hi,jacob in dropbox if we enable auto upload in setting page ,It will automatically upload the camera roll image to cloud, so thats is possible.

Comment: I don't see any way to auto upload pictures from the dropbox app on the iOS app.  There is an option to upload photos, but the dropbox app still has to be opened for it to start uploading it seems, at least when i use it.

Comment: Ok.In setting page one option is there background.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/500

If you look at this description, it does not appear that photos taken with the iOS camera are automatically queued.  All this says is that background uploading can take place, but you likely need to open the app back up for it to pull in the newest images, etc.